# SQL serverless command from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to know if there is a way to run a SQL command inside a C# code without connecting to a database instance.

For example I want to run the following script:

```
SELECT 15/(3+2) AS RESULT
```

And get the result (3) without open a connection to an actual SQL Server instance.

UPDATE: After one hour of the original question

I'm building a system that will calculate indicators based on user input. 
I'm searching for Expression Evaluators to calculate the results (for example 15/(3+5) = 3 or 15/3+5 = 8. I found many, like NCalc, mXparser and many more, but SQL (at least SQL Server) have the `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` expressions which will help a lot by returning null when the denominator is zero or to return null if just one important component of the numerator is null.

Since I will give the user the possibility to create their own indicators it will be much easier to teach using SQL language, because the users already have some degree of SQL.

Comment: If you do not require a connection to pull data from a database then you would be better off doing this as C# code, not SQL code.

Comment: Actually the result would be 3

Comment: So, who or what is supposed to parse and _interpreter_ the query?

Comment: The simple answer is No. Even an In-Memory DB require a connection. I don't know if C# has this feature but Delphi does.

Comment: Why do you want to run a SQL command? Why can't you just write the command in C#?

Comment: @John Cappelletti jajajaja, you are right sorry. I don't have an SQL connection and my brain is burned out

Comment: @IgnacioHanesman Just an FYI, `ISNULL` is a Microsoft proprietary keyword, and not standard ANSI/ISO SQL. The standard alternative would be `COALESCE`. This may be relevant when looking for alternatives to MSSQL, as they are unlikely to be able to evaluate `ISNULL`. ([there are subtle differences but probably irrelevant in your case](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce/))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a lightweight embedded SQL engine like [`SQL CE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) or [`SQLite`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) to evaluate your `select` query?

You can also get close just using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) directly on a regular data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the compute method of a datatable.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim result = dt.Compute("15/(3+2)", "0")
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I really need to use the NULLIF and ISNULL SQL functions, I have edited the question. Thank you for you answer anyway.

Comment: You _need_ to use `NULLIF` or you _want_ to? It sounds like you are comfortable with SQL and know how to handle divide-by-zero problems in that, when all you really need is a parser to do math.

Comment: @DStanley You are right I like to use MSSQL because the clients already know the language.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is a way to run a SQL command inside a C# code
>   without connecting to a database instance.

NO, there is none; cause where or against which data source then your query should execute you think.